# Подключение библиотек в Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

При компиляции кода выдает следующие ошибки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код рабочий, тестировался в Visual Studio. 
Видимо какая-то проблема с заголовочными файлами. Вот как я их подключаю

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: SetConsoleCP - чисто виндовая вещь насколько я знаю. Т.е. тут не заголовочные файлы а вся задумка. Да и лучше текстом а не скрином всё же.

Comment: Код рабочий __для Windows__.

Comment: И да, сейчас вам расскажут о ненадобности постинга скриншотов вместо текста программ/ошибок и будут очень правы.

Comment: Да, про то, что код надо текстом постить, знаю. Но с виртуальной машины скопировать не могу, а переписывать - такое себе занятие

Comment: учитывая, что в коде есть по всей видимости сокеты, нужно будет переделать работу с ними. Как минимум, WSA функций в линуксе нет. Нужно менять на аналоги. И делать такую глупость, как WSAStartup не нужно (просто выпиливается эта часть). SetConsoleCP также не нужно - это опять же анахронизм с винды.

Comment: Плюс, судя по ошибкам и инклюдам, свалена мала куча из C и C++. Плюс используются какие-то windows-only типы SOCKET, DWORD и т.п. Плюс, похоже, namespace std забыто.  А sockaddr_in живёт в <netinet/in.h>

Comment: Пока не закидали камнями, хочу сказать, что код не мой, а из универской методички. Просто пытаюсь разобраться. Но в целом да, шок-контент

Comment: Между прочим, прекрасный повод попробовать сделать из этого переносимую программу :) Главное запомнить: если в программе C++ используется только для `cin/cout` — программе на самом деле не нужен ни cout, ни "++".